# Problem using For loop inside module to iterate over permutations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to write some code to extract all the different subgraphs of a given size from a random graph by creating all the possible permutations of vertices and drawing the subgraph with each of those vertices. However when I attempt to use a For loop to do this, it only draws the first subgraph. I am not very familiar with Mathematica so I am not sure where the issue is.

The individual components that creates the random graph and the list of permutations works, it is only when put together in the loop that it fails to work.

Module creates random graph with n points and edge probability p

```
G[n_, p_] := Module[{A, M}, A = Table[If[i < j, If[RandomReal[] < p, 1, 0], 0], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
  M = A + Transpose[A];
  Return[AdjacencyGraph[M]];]
```

Function to find all the subgraphs of G(n,p) with d vertices

```
Subcount[n_, p_, d_] := 
 Module[{i, ex, per, sub1}, ex = G[n, p]; per = Permutations[Range[n], {d}];
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[per] , i++, Print[i]; 
   sub1 = HighlightGraph[ex, Subgraph[ex, Part[per, i]]]; 
   Return[sub1]];]
```

Tested with n =5, p = 0.4, d = 3

```
Subcount[5, 0.4, 3]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4aQC.jpg 
Gives the output seen through an example test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Subcount[n_, p_, d_] := Module[{i, ex, per, sub1},
  ex = G[n, p];
  per = Permutations[Range[n], {d}];
  Table[{i,{HighlightGraph[ex, Subgraph[ex, Part[per, i]]]}},{i,Length[per]}]];
Subcount[5, 0.4, 3]
```

which should show you all 60 graphs.

Comment: Thanks that works just like I want, just a quick followup How can that be modified so it just stores all of the subgraphs in a list (without displaying them) as I want to check for some properties of the subgraphs and wish to be able to call upon each of them individually

Comment: That works perfectly, I just decided to change it so it would just show the subgraph vertices as those are all I need, thank you, I clearly need to use Mathematica more.